# Can you access statistics for a RavenDB document session

Tags: ravendb

I am doing some performance work in my unit tests and wondering if it was possible to get access to statistics for my RavenDb session (similar to NHibernate session statistics)?

I want to know things like total query count and number of trips to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Berko,
Yes, you can.

Look at the `session.Advanced` property, you have a number of things there. The most important one of them is probably the `NumberOfRequests` that this session made.

Answer (score 0):

Raven DB Profiler can give you some of the information you need.... Here

http://ayende.com/blog/38913/ravendb-mvc-profiler-support